# How to update RecyclerView item without animation?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-animation

I have a `RecyclerView`. When I click a button inside an item in `RecyclerView`, I want to change the color of a `View` in that item. The following is my code and it works fine. But, the problem is the item will have an animation which is ugly. I want to update the item without the animation. How should I do that? By the way, I don't want to turn off the animation, only for this click event.

```
  public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        public ImageView imageView;
        public Button button;

        public ItemViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            //do something
            button.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //change color
            notifyItemChanged(getAdapterPosition());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you try to use `notifyItemChanged(position, Object);`

Comment: @RakshitNawani your answer works!

Comment: Happy to help Cheers !!

Comment: There is a dedicated method to disable just item changed animations:
((SimpleItemAnimator) myRecyclerView.getItemAnimator()).setSupportsChangeAnimations(false);

Ref: https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/SimpleItemAnimator

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Try this

```
notifyItemChanged(position, Object);
```

This will update the position without animating it as we are passing our Object in it.

Try this and do let me know.

For `Kotlin` you can use

```
notifyItemChanged(int position, Unit payload)
```

Comment: @Sam : Happy to help. Cheers !!

Comment: Thank you, man! Somehow did not know such a small thing and useful thing!

Answer (score 13):

Based on the [Rakshit's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45590003/3876285), in **Kotlin 1.2** the following code works fine:

```
notifyItemChanged(position, Unit)
```

Answer (score 12):

There is a dedicated method to disable just item changed animations:

```
((SimpleItemAnimator) myRecyclerView.getItemAnimator()).setSupportsChangeAnimations(false);
```

Ref.: https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/SimpleItemAnimator

Answer (score 6):

in kotlin : recyclerView.itemAnimator = null

in java : recyclerView.setItemAnimator(null);

developer said :
A null return value indicates that there is no animator and that item changes will happen without any animations.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html#getItemAnimator()

Answer (score 4):

```
recyclerView.getItemAnimator().setChangeDuration(0);
```

Or this.

Comment: I don't see `getItemAnimator` method on my `RecyclerView`

Comment: Please put more explanation than a signle one liner code, it doesn't help

Comment: `getItemAnimator()` was added in version `22.0.0`
[Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html#getItemAnimator())

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
csRecyclerView.getItemAnimator().setChangeDuration(0);
```

for more information  [RecyclerView.ItemAnimator](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.ItemAnimator.html#setSupportsChangeAnimations%28boolean%29)

Comment: I don't see `getItemAnimator` on my `RecyclerView`. and I think it will turn off all of the animation I guess.